# Magento 2: Add track order link with the order on Order History Page

Tags: magento2

Add track order link on Order History Page

```
  <block class="Magento\Shipping\Block\Tracking\Link" name="tracking-info-link" template="Magento_Shipping::tracking/link.phtml">
      <arguments>
          <argument name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Track your order</argument>
      </arguments>
  </block>
```

Comment: With every order or only on the history page?

Comment: on histroy page

Comment: what do you mean

Comment: no when you login and click on my order magento opne this url /sales/order/history/ and show orders now i want add 1 more column track your order and want add lnk

Comment: OK, so you have the link for the tracking the URL you want to add on the history page, right?

Comment: yes i want this

Comment: I've added the answer for the same. This code is tested and it is working file. Please check.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Copy the `/vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/order/history.phtml` file in your theme under `/app/design/frontend/[Vendor]/[Theme]/Magento_Sales/templates/order/history.phtml` with below content to add order tracking link.

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

// @codingStandardsIgnoreFile

/** @var \Magento\Sales\Block\Order\History $block */

?>
<?php $_orders = $block->getOrders(); ?>
<?= $block->getChildHtml('info') ?>
<?php if ($_orders && count($_orders)): ?>
    <div class="table-wrapper orders-history">
        <table class="data table table-order-items history" id="my-orders-table">
            <caption class="table-caption"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Orders') ?></caption>
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th scope="col" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order #') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Date') ?></th>
                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getChildHtml('extra.column.header') ?>
                <th scope="col" class="col shipping"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Ship To') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Order Total') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Status') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col actions"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Action') ?></th>
                <th scope="col" class="col actions">Track Order</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_orders as $_order): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order #')) ?>" class="col id"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getRealOrderId() ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Date')) ?>" class="col date"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->formatDate($_order->getCreatedAt()) ?></td>
                    <?php $extra = $block->getChildBlock('extra.container'); ?>
                    <?php if ($extra): ?>
                        <?php $extra->setOrder($_order); ?>
                        <?= /* @noEscape */ $extra->getChildHtml() ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Ship To')) ?>" class="col shipping"><?= $_order->getShippingAddress() ? $block->escapeHtml($_order->getShippingAddress()->getName()) : '&nbsp;' ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Order Total')) ?>" class="col total"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->formatPrice($_order->getGrandTotal()) ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Status')) ?>" class="col status"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_order->getStatusLabel() ?></td>
                    <td data-th="<?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Actions')) ?>" class="col actions">
                        <a href="<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $block->getViewUrl($_order) ?>" class="action view">
                            <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('View Order') ?></span>
                        </a>
                        <?php if ($this->helper('Magento\Sales\Helper\Reorder')->canReorder($_order->getEntityId())) : ?>
                            <a href="#" data-post='<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo
                            $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\Data\Helper\PostHelper::class)
                                ->getPostData($block->getReorderUrl($_order))
                            ?>' class="action order">
                                <span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('Reorder') ?></span>
                            </a>
                        <?php endif ?>
                    </td>
                    <td class="col actions">
                        <a href="#" class="action track" title="Track Your Order"
                           data-mage-init='{"popupWindow": {"windowURL":"<?= $this->helper('\Magento\Shipping\Helper\Data')->getTrackingPopupUrlBySalesModel($_order); ?>","windowName":"trackorder","width":800,"height":600,"left":0,"top":0,"resizable":1,"scrollbars":1}}'>
                            <span>Track Your Order</span>
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <?php if ($block->getPagerHtml()): ?>
        <div class="order-products-toolbar toolbar bottom"><?= $block->getPagerHtml() ?></div>
    <?php endif ?>
<?php else: ?>
    <div class="message info empty"><span><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ __('You have placed no orders.') ?></span></div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Flush the cache after the changes.

***Hope it helps!!!***

Comment: Have you tried this @imtiazau?

Comment: yes worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

> You will need to create the file `customer_account.xml` in the path
>   `Vendor/Module/view/frontend/layout`

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
  <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-custom">
              <arguments>
                 <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">routename/customer/index</argument>
                 <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">My Custom Tab </argument>
               </arguments>
           </block>
      </referenceBlock>
  </body>
</page>
```

For More Details [add Custom Tab in Customer Account in Magento 2](https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/add-custom-tab-customer-account-magento-2.html)